# Create zip archives for Xcode project for versions on two different branches

Tags: ios, xcode, git, zip

I have an Xcode project with two different branches. My client has requested that I send two different zip archives for the two branches, such that opening the first archive would mean seeing the version on the first branch, and opening the second archive would mean seeing the version on the second branch.

However, compressing the project folder while based on the master branch, archiving, and then switching to the other branch, and archiving again, led to the creation of 2 archives that actually behave the same when opened.

My client doesn't want/know how to use git.

Is there any way I can achieve my goal of creating 2 archives, 1 for each branch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you switch branches on your local or on your remote hosting?

Comment: If you did everything on your local branch, then yes, it would have given you two different versions of the code. Unless both your branches are the same currently. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git checkout local_branch_1
$ zip branch_1_archive *
$ git checkout master
$ zip master_archive *
```

The history will not be included in the archives, since `zip` does not include filenames starting with a dot, and the history is in the directory `.git`.

I guess you did not do it that way, if you have identical archives. In that case, please add to your question the commands you used.

You could also add the output of `git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate`, to make sure that `master` and your branch do not point at the same commit.